# Different results between Laravel query builder and raw query Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

These 2 queries returned different of total rows, I cannot identified what was wrong.
I have tried to get the raw query from Laravel, then just ran it on Mysql console, the result was 544 rows.
But when I ran the query builder on PHP CLI, the result was 375 rows.

```
$start_date = '2019-04-01 00:00:00';
$end_date = '2019-04-01 23:59:59';
$sales_channel_ids = '8,20,23,24,31,32,33,37,49,50,69,77,78,79,80,81,82,85,86,87,88,89,90';
$r = DB::table('orders')->leftjoin('order_items', 'order_items.orders_id', '=', 'orders.orders_id')->whereIn('orders.sp_id', [$sales_channel_ids])->whereIn('order_items.status', [9, 11])->whereRaw("orders.shipment_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'")->get();
    
$r->count(); // 375 rows

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN orders_items oi ON oi.jng_sp_orders_id = o.jng_sp_orders_id
WHERE o.sp_id IN (8,20,23,24,31,32,33,37,49,50,69,77,78,79,80,81,82,85,86,87,88,89,90)
AND oi.status IN (9,11)
AND o.shipment_date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-01'");

mysql_num_rows($rs); // 544 rows
```

Comment: Please stop using PHP's ancient, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API, and (even better) upgrade your PHP version to one that would not permit its use.

Answer (score 0):

first, i don't know why the left join condition is different between your query (`orders_id` and `jng_sp_orders_id`) but your laravel query whereIn for sp_id is incorrect because $sales_channel_ids is a string you need to cast it to an array using explode

```
->whereIn('orders.sp_id', explode(",",$sales_channel_ids))
```